# How to check whether text end with some specific string e.g. (2)?

Tags: c#, regex

I have below set of string and i need to test whether any string end with particular pattern `"(\d)"`.

```
atat_vav(1)    
atat_(2)vav(1)  
atat_(2)vav  
atat_(2)vav(1)(12)  
atat_(2)vav(1)(3)
```

I have tried below regex which only tell me that it contain this pattern as below:

```
\((\d*?)\)
```

but i have check that it must contain on the end to the string only. It is should fail the third string in the test.
**Edit:** Correct expression

```
 \((\d+)\)$
```

How can i get the last digit between the brackets if it pass the test??

```
(1) => 1
```

**Solution:** In the matched group you will find the matched content just replace the with \1 back reference it you will get 1 as result.

[Regex Test](https://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/47)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$`(*end of the line anchor*) which asserts that we are at the line end.

```
@"\((\d*)\)$"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/42)

Comment: +1, ohh.. my mistake i was testing all these string together so it was not able to get it correct.. by the way Thanks Mir. @Avinash.. can i get answer of my second question??

Comment: @NiranjanKala: what is the second question?

Comment: How can i get the last digit between the brackets if it pass the test??

Comment: You already have it in Group 1, [see here, on the right](https://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/44). In C#, use `match.Groups[1].Value`.

Comment: @Avinash Raj: Thanks for you help.. i just made a little mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Use a (?=\n|$) at the end. This will match new lines or END.

```
\((\d*?)\)(?=\n|$)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@"\((\d+)\)$"
```

if the digit in between braces is mandatory

and if its a c# which i havent noticed earlier you can do the folloowing to get the value in between the last braces

```
Regex.Match("User (10) name (20)", @"\((\d+)\)$").Groups[1].Value;
```